# Unable to start Apache Airflow webserver due to dagbag /dev/null error

Tags: airflow, airflow-webserver

I have installed apache airflow V 2.1.0 on Ubuntu running on Windows Linux subsystem(WSL).
After installation, I have created an admin user and also set the AIRFLOW_HOME variable in the ~/.bashrc file as below

`export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow`

However, when I'm trying to start the airflow webserver it is not working and I'm getting below text

```
  ____________       _____________
 ____    |__( )_________  __/__  /________      __
____  /| |_  /__  ___/_  /_ __  /_  __ \_ | /| / /
___  ___ |  / _  /   _  __/ _  / / /_/ /_ |/ |/ /
 _/_/  |_/_/  /_/    /_/    /_/  \____/____/|__/
[2021-06-12 03:29:19,807] {dagbag.py:487} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /dev/null
Running the Gunicorn Server with:
Workers: 4 sync
Host: 0.0.0.0:8080
Timeout: 120
Logfiles: - -
Access Logformat:
=================================================================
[2021-06-12 03:29:23 +0530] [12464] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2021-06-12 03:29:23 +0530] [12464] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (12464)
[2021-06-12 03:29:23 +0530] [12464] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2021-06-12 03:29:23 +0530] [12466] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12466
[2021-06-12 03:29:23 +0530] [12467] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12467
[2021-06-12 03:29:23 +0530] [12468] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12468
[2021-06-12 03:29:23 +0530] [12469] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12469
```

Can anyone please help me to get rid of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a user airflow. Basically, it looks like airflow is trying to find a path `/home/airflow` and it couldn't find it or that mount path is missing. I am not sure how ubuntu as a windows subsystem is being configured.